# What's the difference between these two codes to get the sum of infinite series in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, while-loop, infinite-loop

> 1 + 1/(2^4) + 1/(3^4) + 1/(4^4) + ...

This is the infinite series that I'd like to get the sum value. So I wrote this code in MATLAB.

```
n = 1;
numToAdd = 1;
sum = 0;
while numToAdd > 0
    numToAdd = n^(-4);
    sum = sum + numToAdd;
    n = n + 1;
end
disp(sum);
```

But I couldn't get the result because this code occurred an infinite loop. However, the code I write underneath -- it worked well. It took only a second.

```
n = 1;
oldsum = -1;
newsum = 0;
while newsum > oldsum
    oldsum = newsum;
    newsum = newsum + n^(-4);
    n = n+1;
end
disp(newsum);
```

I read these codes again and googled for a while, but coudln't find out the critical point. What makes the difference between these two codes? Is it a matter of precision of double in MATLAB?

Comment: You might be interested in: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function Spoiler alert: `zeta(4)` equals `pi^4/90`.

Comment: I think its because there is a limit to number of significant digits that can be stored in a variable. In the first case, the numToAdd goes close to zero but it can easily be represented as AeB where B increases in the negative direction and number of significant digits in A are easily manageable. In the second case, when new sum is represented as AeB, as B becomes large, then the number of significant digits increase as well upto a limit. When this limit is reached, oldsum and newsum are considered equal. I do not know the limit of number of significant digits. Somebody else might enlighten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first version would have to go down to the minimum value for a double `~10^-308`, while the second will only need to go down to the [machine epsilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon) `~10^-16`. The epsilon value is the largest value `x` such that `1+x = 1`.

This means the first version will need approximately **`10^77`** iterations, while the second only needs **`10^4`**.

Answer (score 1):

The problem boils down to this:

```
x = 1.23456789; % Some random number
xEqualsXPlusEps = (x == x + 1e-20)
ZeroEqualsEps =   (0 ==     1e-20)
```

`xEqualsXPlusEps` will be `true`, while `ZeroEqualsEps` is false. This is due to the way floating point arithmetic works. The value `1e-20` is smaller than the least significant bit of `x`, so `x+1e-20` won't be larger than `x`. However `1e-20` is not considered equal to `0`. In comparison to `x`, `1e-20` is relatively small, whereas in comparison to `0`, `1e-20` is not small at all.

To fix this problem you would have to use:

```
while numToAdd > tolerance %// Instead of > 0
```

where `tolerance` is some small number greater than zero.